# Oracle SQL combine output from two queries into single output

Tags: sql, oracle

I am not able to create tables, but I want to combine the output from two queries into a single output. What I currently have

Output 1:

```
Date    Promo   Count
1-Aug   PROMO1  8
1-Aug   PROMO2  3
2-Aug   PROMO1  3
2-Aug   PROMO2  4
```

Output 2:

```
Date    Promo                 Count
1-Aug   DIFFERENTKINDOFPROMO1   3
2-Aug   DIFFERENTKINDOFPROMO1   5
```

What I'm trying to get (combine Output 1 and 2)

```
    Date    Promo   Count

    1-Aug   PROMO1  8
    1-Aug   PROMO2  3
    1-Aug   DIFFERENTKINDOFPROMO1   3
    2-Aug   PROMO1  3
    2-Aug   PROMO2  4
    2-Aug   DIFFERENTKINDOFPROMO1   5
```

As mentioned, I don't have the ability to create any tables, so I'm trying to do this on the fly so I get the final combined output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table1
union all
select * from table2;
```

Comment: and if you need it sorted `SELECT * FROM(SELECT ... UNION..) ORDER BY 1`

Comment: You don't even need the subquery. Just put `ORDER BY 1` at the end of the answer query (moving the `;`).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above this would be the final query..
select * from table1
union all
select * from table2 
order by 1;

Answer (score 0):

If the ordering matters, then this needs a bit of care:

```
select date, promo, count
from ((select date, promo, count, 1 as which from table1
      ) union all
      (select date, promo, count, 2 as which from table2
      )
     ) t
order by date, which;
```

It is not possible to guarantee the original ordering within each table (because there doesn't seem to be an ordering key for each table), but you can be sure that table 2 records follow table 1 on any given day.